# Flutter send firebase notification to token

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

So i have a chat app and i want it so that i can get a notification once someone sends me a message. The thing is that i implemented firebase messaging and i can receive a notification if i send it from firebase. I want to add it such as once i press the send button i can directly send the notification to a token within the app for instance something like:

```
send notification{
   to token : here the receiver token
   title : the title of the notification
   description : the description of the notification  
}
```

is it possible to have something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for helping,

If anyone wants to use REST POST API, here it is, use the Postman with below configuration

**URL:**
`https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

**Header:**

```
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "key=<Server_key>"
```

**BODY:**

```
{
    "to": "<Device FCM token>",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Check this Mobile (title)",
      "body": "Rich Notification testing (body)",
      "mutable_content": true,
      "sound": "Tri-tone"
      },
      
   "data": {
    "url": "<url of media image>",
    "dl": "<deeplink action on tap of notification>"
      }
}
```